# Реализована ли веб-доступность (accessibility) на законодательном уровне в рунете?

Tags: html5, веб-программирование, frontend

Если да, хотел бы получить ссылки на тексты законов в Украине, России, Беларуси и других странах, охватываемых рунетом.

Нашел вот эту ссылку: https://www.w3.org/WAI/policies/, но среди предлагаемых стран нет постсовестких.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в России есть ГОСТ, но обязаны его выполнять только государственные службы. Т.е. сайт президента обязан, а сайт ООО Рога и копыта может не заморачиваться

Comment: А где-то текст ГОСта почитать можно?

Comment: https://medium.com/web-standards/a11y-and-law-a81dd9dd5fc8 о, вот прямо для вас статью написали 